# Events in Onvif Device Manager

Tags: c#, onvif

I'm developing an application that needs to receive events from cameras(eg. motion detection) using ONVIF protocol.

I've downloaded the latest ONVIF Device Manage version from [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/onvifdm/code/HEAD/tree/), and was able to compile and run it.

I would like to create something similar to DeviceEventsView.xaml of Onvif Device Manager in my own source using the libraries provided, however I'm having a tough time figuring out what part of the code is from the library itself.

Can someone be so kind as to explain me how it can be done?

Here's what I manage to do so far(this code might be completely wrong):

```
OdmSession session = new OdmSession(this.session);
IObservable<OnvifEvent> x = session.GetBaseEvents(554);
x.Subscribe(
    onvifEvent =>
    {
        try
        {
            // don't know exactly what to do here
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            dbg.Error(err);
        }
    }, err =>
    {
        dbg.Error(err);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question. Here's the code that solved my problem:

```
onvif.utils.OdmSession odmSession = new onvif.utils.OdmSession(session);
odmSession.GetPullPointEvents().Subscribe(
    onvifEvent =>
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var s in onvifEvent.message.Data.simpleItem)
            {
                if (s.name == "LogicalState")
                {
                    // code here
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        } 
});
```

Comment: hi, can you explain more about it? I have the same problem , and the events don't fire. thanks.